# Processing nested objects

Tags: javascript, express

I'm making an API. I get data from an external resource. Then comes the business logic and as a result I get this response:

```
 {
  data: [
    {
      BTC: {
        USD: 46389.84,
        RUB: 3406131.15,
        EUR: 39472.76,
      },
    },
    {
      ETH: {
        USD: 3215.65,
        RUB: 235786.69,
        EUR: 2741.52,
      },
    },
  ],

}
```

How can I get rid of such nesting and get as a result:

```
 {
  data: {
    BTC: {
      USD: 46389.84,
      RUB: 3406131.15,
      EUR: 39472.76,
    },

    ETH: {
      USD: 3215.65,
      RUB: 235786.69,
      EUR: 2741.52,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The problem is that it is difficult to use such data later and I would like to get rid of the excess (so that it is like in the second example)

I tried for of, for in, Object. entries . It didn't bring any results

Comment: I've often wished there was something analogous to hoogle for JS, which would give us a structured way to look up answers to such questions as "how to concatenate an array of objects into a single object". For the moment you might have some luck searching for that phrase or a similar one via a search engine.

Comment: So give a [mre] of that.

Comment: @neverMind: *"I tried for of, for in, Object. entries"* - Can you demonstrate that attempt and indicate specifically which operation is producing an unexpected result when you debug?

Comment: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) merges objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects in the array `data` do not contain keys with objects as values or further nesting, the following will work:

```js
const flatData = obj.data.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...cur, ...acc}), {});
const newObj = { data: flatData };
```

There are two main components:

- `{...cur, ...acc}`: The `...x` is called a spread. It basically unpacks an array or an object in place. If we unpack two things sequentially, we essentially merge them into a single object/array.
- `x.reduce((acc, cur) => /* new acc */, initialValue)`: The reduce method transforms an array into something else, by iterating over all properties and allowing us to incrementally build an `accumulate` object (`acc`). We are supposed to return the new `acc` from the iterator function at each step.

Comment: Or just `{data: Object.assign({}, ...obj.data)}`

Comment: Both of these options fail for complex objects in the `data` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const response = {
    data: [
      {
        BTC: {
          USD: 46389.84,
          RUB: 3406131.15,
          EUR: 39472.76,
        },
      },
      {
        ETH: {
          USD: 3215.65,
          RUB: 235786.69,
          EUR: 2741.52,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

const data = {
    data: {},
  };

response.data.map((item) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item).map((key) => key);
  const values = Object.values(item).map((value) => value);
  data.data[keys[0]] = values[0];
});
```

you can use the reduce method it works great also if you want to do something manually you can do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The `deepmerge()` function [here](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/helpers/deepmerge/) is a more robust solution than the shallow copy you get via  `Object.assign()` or the spread operator

```
var deepMerge = function () {

    // Setup merged object
    var newObj = {};

    // Merge the object into the newObj object
    var merge = function (obj) {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                // If property is an object, merge properties
                if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
                    newObj[prop] = deepMerge(newObj[prop], obj[prop]);
                } else {
                    newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        merge(arguments[i]);
    }

    return newObj;

};


const response = {
    data: [
      {
        BTC: {
          USD: 46389.84,
          RUB: 3406131.15,
          EUR: 39472.76,
          SOME_OBJ: {
            USD: 46389.84,
            RUB: 3406131.15,
            EUR: 39472.76,
          }
        },
      },
      {
        ETH: {
          USD: 3215.65,
          RUB: 235786.69,
          EUR: 2741.52,
        },
      },
    ],
}

let deepData = {};

response.data.forEach(obj => { deepData = deepMerge(obj, deepData); })
```